# how to access List Object Methods?

Tags: java, list, object

I have a Seed key as below:
[image]
I know that if I want to access the class methods, they should be static:

here is my Cardkeyword class:

```
public class CardKeyword implements Comparable<CardKeyword> {

    public CardKeyword(String stem) {
        this.stem = stem;
    }
    public  String  getStem() {
        return this.stem;
    }
    //some methods
}
```

here is my main class:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String Seedurl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science";
      List Seedkey=getXKeywords(Seedurl, 1);
  }

  public static List getXKeywords(String Url, int X) throws Exception {
      String html = get(Url);
      String plaintext = Jsoup.parse(html).text();
      List<CardKeyword> wordlist = KeywordsExtractor.getKeywordsList(plaintext);
      List lst = wordlist.subList(0, X);
      return lst;
  }
```

I want to get the stem from the Seedkey but I was not able to do it. How can I do it? If I change the `getStem` method to `public static getStem()`, it gives me error.

Comment: You need to get an instance from the list.  You also need to use generics.

Comment: What is the error and on while like does it occur?

Comment: but I already have the object there, why do I need to do it?

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve]? Like what is `getXKeywords`? It sounds like youre just asking how to index a list

Comment: @Nickool generics make it easier to access the element of the list without getting an error at runtime.

Comment: sure I will update the code

Comment: I still think you're asking how to do `Seedkey.get(0).getStem()`

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, I was not able to, Warrior changed the code and now I can.

Comment: Well, yes, and that's what Peter was referring to by generics

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get the term generics meant CardKeyword here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getXKeywords` returns a list, you have to iterate its `CardKeyword` items to call `getStem` method.
By the way in your current code the list is not parametrized. Replace `List Seedkey` with `List<CardKeyword> Seedkey` to deal with `CardKeyword` objects and not `Object` objects.